# Add a new row below when the documents identifies a number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) in the upper row

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a table with different columns. One of the columns indicates how many people we will accommodate in an apartment. We need to create as many new rows as there are people in the apartment. The code I have now is to add 1 row below range X:X. I need a number of rows X to be added based on the number that appears in column K and not based on the selected range.

I have achieved the function to add X number of rows below, but I cannot find the way to identify de number and activate the action.

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elv8i.png)

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDlI3.png)

```
function guests2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 2, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 3, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('5:5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 4, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('6:6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 5, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('7:7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 6, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
};
```

Comment: Still can't understand what you're trying to achieve, I won't be able get anything from that macro code., you want to add rows below  the data based on sum of guest in column K right?

Comment: @vector Exacly, the only thing is that I don't need to add rows bades on the sum of the guest in column K. Just based on the value in each row. I have add the image of the final result. Ej - 1 guest -> Add 1 row below. 2 guests -> add 2 rows below...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem statement in comment and final result image:-

> the only thing is that I don't need to add rows bades on the sum of
> the guest in column K. Just based on the value in each row. I have add
> the image of the final result. Ej - 1 guest -> Add 1 row below. 2
> guests -> add 2 rows below...

Try this sample script:-

```
function addRows()
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('replace it with sheet name') // put your sheet name in quotes
  const range = ssSource.getRange('K:K').getValues().flat();
  var addedRow = 1
  var lastadded = 0
  for( var i = 1 ; i < range.length ; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      addedRow = addedRow + lastadded + 1
      ssSource.insertRowsAfter(addedRow, range[i])
      lastadded = range[i]
    }
    catch(err)
    {
       console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:-

[insertRowsAfter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany)